# Run create-react-app from sub-folder

Tags: reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

I'm using  [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). I want to run my code from **nested directory/sub-directory**. My directory structure is as per the screenshot.

[image]

I'm using `npm start` command to run it localy.

I have update my package.json file like

```
"homepage": "/foobar/"
```

and my index file

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router basename={'foobar'}>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <RouteList />
        </div>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

for the routing plugin - [link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter) I have included node_modules into both directory for the testing purpose.

but still I'm getting below error while trying to run npm start from the root directory.

```
Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.html
  Searched in: C:\git\AccountManager\public
```

It's working fine from the inner folder. Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You could change directory to foobar first run npm start. I would incorporate that in my npm start command so that it now looks like the following:

**package.json**

```
{
  ...
  "scripts" : {
    "start": "cd foobar && react-scripts start",
    ...
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but I wanna run it from the parent directory.

Comment: Just to be clear the root directory is the folder AccountManager right? Which also contains your package.json?

Comment: Correct. Package.json is only available in root.

Comment: So if you change the npm start in package.json to `cd foobar && react-scripts start`, when you run npm run start it should start the react app successfully.

Answer (score 1):

So far I managed to make it work only if I move only `index.html` to `public` folder in the root, or by installing all React `node-modules` under `src` folder